# App show black Screen for a 2 to 4 second when perform action on firebase

Tags: android, firebase

When I upload, fetch or delete data on Firebase Real time and after done this  launch a new activity, the application shows a black screen for a while and then shows the new activity. Please help me. I will really appreciate.

My code of one activity

```
 private void sendTextToFirebase() {
    //here uploading the data
    myRef.child(selected_Category).child(String.valueOf(UniqueId)).setValue(member).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

            Intent homeActivity = new Intent(ManualCardActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
            startActivity(homeActivity);
            finish();

        }
    });

}
```

When I remove new activity, launching code app works perfectly.

Here the last part of my run log:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.webfabricant.schedular, PID: 13303
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.webfabricant.schedular/com.webfabricant.schedular.HomeActivity}:
>   com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Calls to
>   setPersistenceEnabled() must be made before any other usage of
>   FirebaseDatabase instance.
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3171)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3308)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:113)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:71)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2034)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:226)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7191)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:576)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:942)
>        Caused by: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Calls to setPersistenceEnabled() must be made before any other usage of
>   FirebaseDatabase instance.
>           at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.assertUnfrozen(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:347)
>           at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.setPersistenceEnabled(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:315)
>           at com.webfabricant.schedular.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:53)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7376)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7367)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3151)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3308) 
>           at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:113) 
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:71) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2034) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:226) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7191) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:576) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:942) 
>   I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 13303 SIG: 9

Comment: Can you post your logs from RUN tag from Android Studio here? And which device are you using for testing?

Comment: i done this please help if you can thanks for giving your meaning full time.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are working a heavy task on the app's main thread (UI thread). 
Make use of AsyncTask or RxJava for running the task parallelly on the background thread. Go for AsyncTask it will be easy for you to understand.

[AsyncTask Documentation Link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask)

Comment: i study this and i use this but problem still not gone.And here i found a thing that if i remove these lines  Intent homeActivity = new Intent(ManualCardActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
            startActivity(homeActivity);
            finish();     no problem occure work perfect

Comment: Thats because finish() is used when you want the user to be taken to the previous screen just before the current screen that you are on. So, u are calling startActivity() as well as finish() due to which the IDE gets consfused and executes both of them thus leading to tht slight glitch.

Comment: Thank you so much bro for your time i really appreciate that.but bro i solved this.     by putting Firebase work on new Runnable Thread. and put the of line firebase sync code in the start of app (splash screen now it's working cool) Thanks again for giving your time

Comment: Most Welcome. Just remember never use the two functions together.

Comment: Please accept the ans as accepted so that others may know the solution as well.